# Reference a specific password-encoder in my security-config.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-mybatis

i am using spring security for login authorization.
in my security-config.xml i am using the following code:

```
  <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
       <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
       <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-
           username-query="SELECT username, password,1 as enabled
           FROM users WHERE username=?" authorities-by-
           username-query="SELECT username, authority,1 as enabled 
           FROM users  WHERE username =?" />
      </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
```

but in my database i already have an encrypted password using a customized function that is not a pure md5 hash.
my question is can i call this function from my security-config.xml instead of

```
<password-encoder hash="md5"/>
```

or if there another way?

thank you in advance.

Comment: WRT "customized function": ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*" When saving a password verifier use a peer reviewed and recommended function such as `PBKDF2` (recommended by NIST), `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your custom password encoder (create a class that implements `PasswordEncoder`) which will call your customiwed function.

In your XML, change :

```
<password-encoder hash="md5"/>
```

with :

```
<password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
```

which passwordEncoder is the name of your class/bean implementing `PasswordEncoder`.

More details [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt) or [here](https://egkatzioura.com/2016/10/05/spring-security-and-custom-password-encoding/).